# Button click issue in continuously changing data

Tags: angular

I am creating one table,in which data is updating continuously.In each row there is one button.We have add one popup on click event of button.Some how that button is blinking due to change in data. and not able to click the button.

I have tried @ViewChild(https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) ,but it does not work for me.

```
 <tbody *ngFor="let runner of fancyRunners">
  <tr class="spacer">
    <td><button onload="loadBtn(runner.id)"  id="book-match-{{runner.id}}"   runat="server"  (click)="showAlert(runner)"  class="button rounded-full-btn cancel-btn custom-button">Book</button></td>
    <td class="priority-3"><b>{{runner.back2 | round}}</b><br />{{runner.backValue2 | round}}</td>
    <td class="priority-3"><b>{{runner.back1 | round}}</b><br />{{runner.backValue1 | round}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Below code is in ts file and running on 200ms

```
  if(JSON.parse(message.body).fancy!=null){
  this.fancy = JSON.parse(message.body).fancy;
  }
  this.fancyRunners = this.fancy.runners;
```

I just want to button to be click.that button should be rendered first time ,other than that only other data should be change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this reassignment `this.fancyRunners = this.fancy.runners;` the rows are getting rerendered and your button is blinking.
Don't reassign every time to 'fancyRunners', write a logic to assign for 1st time and then for next time update the array(fancyRunners).

Comment: Thanks @Prawin Thanks for your answer.you just saved my day.